# "not-well-formed" error in FF error console when using PrimePush

Tags: javascript, primefaces, firebug

I'm using:

Linux
PrimeFaces 3.4.1
Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
FireFox 10.0.7

I have a message-driven bean that when fired, I want to send via PrimePush data that will appear in the browser using growl. This is what is in the onMessage() of the MDB. This part seems to work ok as the browser is receiving something.

```
pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
pushContext.push("/notifications",
    new FacesMessage("Test Summary", "Test Detail"));
```

When this MDB fires, I get the following from within the firefox error console.

```
Error: not well-formed
Source File: http://localhost:8080/test/primepush/notifications?X-Atmospheretracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=1.0&X-Atmosphere-Transport=long-polling&X-Cache-Date=0&_=1351363941008
Line: 1, Column: 1
Source Code:
{"data":{"summary":"Test Summary","detail":"Test Detail","severity":"INFO 0","rendered":false}}

Error: growl is not defined
Source File: http://localhost:8080/test/test.xhtml
Line: 25
```

Here's the code in text.xhtml.

```
<h:form id="test_form">

    <p:growl id="growl" for="items" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notifications"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleMessage(data) {
            data.severity = 'info';
            growl.show([data]);
        }
    </script>

</h:form>
```

Comment: i think it should be growl.show([data]); just a typo in the javascript code

Comment: I put growl back but I still get the same results, only with growl as undefined instead of messages. Made changes in question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" />
```

outside the form

look at: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/facesmessage.jsf

Comment: I placed growl outside the form and have been using the showcase as example, but still many of the errors I show in the update.

Comment: i also had those at some point, but cant remember what i did to get past them. Ill post back if I figure it out

Comment: Ok, I can certainly say those errors are a different problem so I've removed them and this fixes the undefined.